# SQL Query to Bucket Table Items

Tags: sql, metabase

I am trying to bucket values within my table by the range they fall in, for example, if my table is the following:

```
course_name | current enrollment
course_1    | 10
course_2    | 200
course_3    | 500
```

I get the following result:

```
enrollment_range | courses
10               | 1
100              | 1
500              | 1
```

So far, I have the following:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN courses.current_enrollment >= 500 THEN 500
    WHEN courses.current_enrollment >= 250 THEN 250
    WHEN courses.current_enrollment >= 100 THEN 100
    WHEN courses.current_enrollment >= 50 THEN 50
    WHEN courses.current_enrollment >= 30 THEN  30
    WHEN courses.current_enrollment >= 10 THEN 10
  END enrollment_range, count() AS total
FROM courses
GROUP BY enrollment_range
ORDER BY enrollment_range ASC
```

but I end up with an extra result that is the total number of courses I have, so I get something like the following:

```
enrollment_range | courses
10               | 1
100              | 1
500              | 1
                 | 3
```

Comment: Your query would not produce zero values, so I don't believe that is the query you are really running.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that was a mistake on my part in copying the result over. I made the necessary edits. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: There is no way to produce the final result using the sql query you provided.   I guess you need to at least have something like:   WHEN courses.current_enrollment >= 10 and  courses.current_enrollment <30 THEN '10-30'  to show the final result.

Comment: @TianyunLing Once again, a mistake on my part. I copied result down wrong. Necessary edits have been made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In you sql, you should use a group in the count. In my SQL server, I can produce the correct result using the following script :

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN current_enrollment >= 500 THEN 500
    WHEN current_enrollment >= 250 THEN 250
    WHEN current_enrollment >= 100 THEN 100
    WHEN current_enrollment >= 50 THEN 50
    WHEN current_enrollment >= 30 THEN  30
    WHEN current_enrollment >= 10 THEN 10
  END as enrollment_range, t.course_name, t.count
FROM courses 

join 
( select  Count(course_name) as count,course_name FROM courses group by course_name ) t

on courses.course_name = t.course_name
```

Comment: I currently have a `GROUP BY enrollment_range`. Wouldn't that serve the same purpose?

Comment: You never show any 'group by' in you code. Also, is you cource_2 100 or 200?

Comment: The additional courses was caused by courses whose enrollment is below 10. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The extra result was the count of courses that did not fall within the specified brackets, in this case, courses with enrollment below 10.